# How can I instantiate a model in Lifecycle callbacks in sails?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

How can I instantiate a model in Lifecycle callbacks different than this? After I delete a record on the parent model I want to delete those associated records of the son model in afterDestroy.
For example:

```
/**
 * Survey.js
 *
 */

  attributes: {
    question: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    active: {
      type: 'boolean'
    },

    // Below is all specification for relations to another models
    answers: {
      collection: 'answer',
      via: 'answer'
    }
  },

  // Lifecycle Callbacks
  afterDestroy: function (destroyedRecords, cb) {
    answer.destroy({survey: destroyedRecords[0].id}).exec(function(err, answers) {
      console.log(answers);
    });
    cb();
  }
});
```

With this I received an error that 'answer' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
To instantiate a model in Lifecycle callbacks in Sails different than 'this' you need you need to precede the model with sails.models.
For the previous code:

```
  // Lifecycle Callbacks
  afterDestroy: function (destroyedRecords, cb) {
    sails.models.answer.destroy({survey: destroyedRecords[0].id}).exec(function(err, answers) {
      console.log(answers);
    });
    cb();
```